# Fazendo scroll page no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

boa tarde! 
estou criando um thema no wordpress com scroll page.

minha paginas estão dividas por slug, page-servicos, page-portifolio e etc..
só que quando coloco para ele fazer o loop ele não lista o conteudo das páginas no caso dos page.php e sim do single.php, quando apago o loop ele lista normal o que eu digito.

segue o meu index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="services">
<?php get_template_part('page','service'); ?>
</section>

<!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
<section id="portfolio" class="bg-light-gray">
<?php get_template_part('page','portifolio'); ?>
</section>

<!-- About Section -->
<section id="about">
 <?php get_template_part('page','quemsomos'); ?>
</section>

<!-- Team Section -->
<section id="team" class="bg-light-gray">
 <?php get_template_part('page','equipe'); ?>
</section>

<!-- Clients Aside -->
<aside class="clients">
 <?php get_template_part('page','clientes'); ?>
</aside>

<!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact">
<?php get_template_part('page','contatos'); ?>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

segue o page-service.php

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
  <h2 class="section-heading">Services</h2>
  <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row text-center">
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
<p>
  <?php the_content();?>
</p>
<?php endwhile; else:?>
<?php endif;?>
</div>
</div>
```

talvez ele não esteja abrindo o conteudo, pois não está chamando uma url e sim um ID
ex: http://localhost/wordpress/#services

estou usando o plugin **Page scroll to id**

Alguém poderia me da um help de como fazer um thema one-page scroll em wordpress? algum tutorial bom?

Comment: Essas seções são categorias, tags, post-types...? E você quer listar todos os posts em cada seção ou limitar a quantidade?

Comment: @RicardoBRGWeb séria páginas, cada sessão dessa é uma página.

Answer (score 1):

O `get_template_part` é só uma forma ed reutilizar o código mais facilmente. É uam forma de apdronizar enter os temas a forma de usar o include no PHP.

Seu template não funciona porque ele não atualiza a query, só cria um novo loop. Como o Loop original provavelmente só tinha uma página, a home, quando você chama de novo o loop dentro das seções ele não acha mais nada porque já chegou ao final.

Pro que você quer fazer, o melhor é usar `get_pages()` para retornar uma array dos objetos das páginas. Assim:

index.php

```
<?php 
get_header();
$pages = get_pages();
foreach ($pages as $page){
echo '<section id="'.$page->title.'">';?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
     <h2 class="section-heading"><?php $page->title?></h2>
      <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3> 
   </div>
  </div> 
<div class="row text-center"> 
   <p>
  <?php $page->post_content; ?>

</p>

</div>
</div>
</section>
<?php
  }
 get_footer();
?>
```